# error in converting sting to system .collection generic list <string>

Tags: c#

```
public static List<string> Symbols
        {
            get
            {
                return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Symbols"];



                string[] sys1 = Sys.Split(',');
                Symbols = new List<string>();
                foreach (string item in sys1)
                {
                    Symbols.Add(item.Trim());

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

It's returning a string

```
return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Symbols"];
```

and you need to return `List<string>`, so you rather want to do this:

```
var Sym = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Symbols"];
```

and at the end add:

```
return Symbols;
```

it should look like:

```
public static List<string> Symbols
{
    get
    {
        var sym = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Symbols"];
        return sym.Split(',').Select(x=>x.Trim()).ToList();
    }
}
```

I've made improvement by using Linq to select trimmed values instead of using foreach.

original one (corrected)

```
public static List<string> Symbols
{
    get
    {
        Sys = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Symbols"];
        string[] sys1 = Sys.Split(',');
        Symbols = new List<string>();
        foreach (string item in sys1)
        {
            Symbols.Add(item.Trim());

        }
        return Symbols;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

as far as I understand, you want to return one value list like this:

```
public static List<string> Symbols
{
    get
    {
        var sym = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Symbols"];
        return new List<string>() { sym };
    }
}
```

Comment: Although technically correct, I would suggest using the `for` loop as in the example code since we're obviously dealing with a novice. Or at least explaining how it translates to LINQ.

Comment: please tell me by using For each loop .plzz

Comment: @Rik I think you're right. I thought my explainations is clear but may be hard to understand because of code.

Comment: @Mohit here you go, corrected version using foreach

Comment: dude this one I had already did ..but I want to use as:-             return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Symbols"];      after that I AM NOT ABLE TO DO IT ...

Comment: @Mohit 1. `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Symbols"]` this is string, not list of strings 2. Rest of your code is not accessible due to this return 3. Explain exactly what is in this config entry and what do you want to get

Comment: get
            {
                return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Symbols"];
                string[] a = new List<string>();
                foreach (string item in a)


                string[] sys1 = Sys.Split(',');
                Symbols = new List<string>();
                foreach (string item in sys1)
                {
                    Symbols.Add(item.Trim());

                }
            }....LIKE THIS

Comment: @Mohit explain what do you want this code to do

Comment: I want to return to another class where I called symbol over there

Comment: @Mohit that is obvious ... 1. What is in config 2. how it should be parsed

Comment: <add key="Symbols" value="F:FCPO\X13"/>...this is in config ...

Comment: @Mohit so you want to return list containing **ALWAYS** one value, yes?

Comment: no ...if I want to add it will be consider that as well .

Comment: @Mohit how am I supossed to undarstand anything here? You are not providing any information. Specify what do you want and then we can talk.

Comment: the question what I asked is the same ..I am getting an error in converting sting to system .collection generic list <string>.how should I can handle this error

Comment: @Mohit My answer clears it. All my solutions are making this code work without exception.

Comment: can any body else  know how to do it ??in the way that I want

Comment: @Mohit the problem is you haven't explained 'your way'

Comment: @wudzik I want to do like this:-                                      public static string Logger
        {
            get
            {
                return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Logger"];
            }
        }                                                            this is an example,now want to use as it is with Symbols

Comment: so change `public static List<string> Symbols` to `public static string Symbols` and this will work

Comment: after that how to use the other part ..plz give me answer .how can I do ...

Comment: no ..but I am having  an list of data ....??

Comment: @Mohit I'm lost, you want to return string and you are creating `List<string>`, man ....

Comment: <add key="symbols" value="F:FCPO\\X13,F:FCPO\\Z13,F:FCPO\\F14,F:FCPO\\G14, F:FCPO\\H14 "/>...if this will be the case ...so how I will do ???

Comment: @Mohit use my first or second code ...

Comment: ...I m returning symbol as this ..Config.Symbols,

Comment: @Mohit and? What's the problem?!

Comment: problem is ..return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Symbols"];error in converting sting to system .collection generic list <string>giving me error

Comment: @Mohit really? Do you understand your code a bit? I suggested you to split that string and return list, what's wrong with that solution?!!

Comment: can u give me code ??

Comment: @Mohit are you serious? In my answer there are 2 suggested code samples.

Comment: @wudzik Wow. I must say I commend your patience with this guy.

Comment: @wudzik  Symbols = new List<string>();
in this line it is referring to Read only ...??/

Comment: @Rik I give up ... Do you have any idea what he wants?